# Trying to clean date column but having difficulty; ending up with calculated column error

Tags: sql-server, date, t-sql, calculated-columns

I have a dataset and I a particular column 'Last_DCR_Date' is in 'varchar' data type format, and my goal is to convert it to DATE format, but so far I've not been able to.

An example of the data in the 'Last_DCR_Date' column looks like this : '24-11-2023', and is in nvarchar.

And I want to transform it to '2023-11-24'.
I'll really appreciate the help

I have tried creating new ('day', 'month', 'year') columns by using:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
ADD day AS SUBSTRING (Last_DCR_Date, 1, 2)
```

....and so on and so forth for the remaining two.

But having done that, I then tried creating a new column by concatenating the 3 columns, e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
ADD new_DCR_Date AS CONCAT_WS('/', day, month, year)
```

But SQL Server says I can't perform that with computed columns

Comment: Dates have no format, they're binary values. If you store dates in string fields you have a *critical* bug. Especially when it's such a custom, unsortable format. Never store dates as text. There's no way to ensure someone won't insert an invalid string or a string with a different format. The real solution is to use a `date` field and convert the data when inserting it, not after the fact. If that's not possible, import the data into a staging table, parse the text column into another `date` column (the answer shows one way to do this) and then import that data in the target table.

Comment: How are you loading the data? All languages and tools have ways of parsing date strings into actual dates.

Comment: The problem you have is because you cannot use nested calculated columns (calculated column cannot use another calculated column in it's expression). You could probably just do: `AS convert(date, last_dcr_date, 105)` or just fix the original string to be a date

Comment: Thanks yall, I done worked it out.
Preciate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You  can alter column to data type `Date` And select data with appropriate format. Here is sample code:

```
ALTER TABLE SampleTable
ADD New_DCR_Date DATE; -- it will automatically convert if data has same format

UPDATE SampleTable
SET New_DCR_Date = CONVERT(DATE, Last_DCR_Date, 105); --yyyy-MM-dd
```

Here is the [fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/Z_EZ_BfP) .

Comment: Yeah thanks that worked.
It didnt work at first cuz some cells in the column had non-date data (e.g. " -- "), but after REPLACING them with empty string (i.e. " ") .
I had no problem converting the dates. Thanks man

Comment: @DaleK, what do you mean by "accepting" an answer?

Btw, This is the first question I've ever asked a subject question on StackOverflow.

Comment: @DaleK thanks I've seen it.
Preciate man